# What is the recommended/best approach to serve large number of assets (images, audio, video) for a consumer application?

Tags: google-app-engine

Option A : From GAE database 
Option B : File System access in GAE
Option C : File System access (CDN) outside GAE like Amazon S3?

or any other options? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an App Engine app, you should use the [the Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/).

If you need stand-alone storage, try [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) or [Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/).

The first is tightly coupled to App Engine; the others are platform-agnostic and controlled via public APIs. They're all pretty similar in terms of behavior and pricing.

Comment: And Google has announced that they plan to more tightly integrate Storage for Developers into GAE (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) but it is on the bottom of the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, its a GAE app.

Isn't it better to go with CDN storage for assets (which doesn't require updates) in terms of performance (& cost) compared with blobstore? 

Accessing assets from CDN won't need an instance of GAE app (of-course, tight integration will help on the secure access to assets).

Comment: Unlike datastore objects, blobstore objects can be served directly without invoking your App Engine app. It's designed for exactly this purpose.